When I add a new file the parent folder remains "green" unmodified
Step to reproduce the problem:

create new folder for example named "1"
with gitbash create a repo, "git init"
now the icon on folder "1" is correctly "green"
now create new file "file1.txt" in this folder
with gitbash add this in repo, "git add ."
now the icon on folder "1" is correctly "red" as modified
with gitbash add this in repo, "git commit -m "vers1"
now the icon on folder "1" is correctly "green" as unmodified
now create new file "file2.txt" in this folder
with gitbash add this in repo, "git add ."
now the icon on folder "1" is not correctly "green" as unmodified
WHY ?
Why does the second creation of a new file in the same folder no longer work ?

I expected that tortoisegit even after inserting a new file in the same folder would show the states correctly
